# how can I write the code inside Application class to get Toast message every 5 seconds from the background

Tags: android

I am new to android and I want to get a Toast message from the background every 5 seconds but my app becomes not responding. I spent all the day to solve this problem :( but I can't
Can anyone help me? 
thanks,

here is my code:

```
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        System.out.println("Application Created");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {    
         @Override
      public void run() {
        service1();
         while (true) {
           try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

         @Override
      public void run() {
        // here to update the UI
        }
       });    
      } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
     }
    }
   }
  }).start();
}

      private void service1() {    
    Toast.makeText(appApplication.this, "Service 1",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `runOnUiThread()` when you want to update your UI from a Non-UI Thread, something like this:

```
private void showMessage() {
  new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      while (true) {
        try {
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
          });
          Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }.start();
}
```

Or you can use **Timer** with **TimerTask** and **Handler**:

```
Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask;
//we are going to use a handler to be able to run in our TimerTask
final Handler handler = new Handler();

// Call this to start showing the message.
private void startTimer() {
  //set a new Timer
  timer = new Timer();

  //initialize the TimerTask's job
  timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
      //use a handler to run process
      handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            /**************************/
            /** Do your process here **/
            /**************************/
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      });
    }
  };

  //schedule the timer, start run TimerTask then run every 5000ms i.e 5 seconds.
  timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 5000);
}

// Call this to stop the timer.
private void stopTimerTask() {
  //stop the timer, if it's not already null
  if (timer != null) {
    timer.cancel();
    timer = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: @ ישו אוהב אותך Thanks for helping. it works fine at the UI side. but I need to see "Service 1" message in the background (at the logcat) every 5 minute.

Comment: Ohh.. How about using the timer part? If you want to see message in logcat, you can use Log.d (TAG, "message"); instead of Toast. And try to avoid using Thread.sleep because it's expensive. Imho